# Disable per-application input language in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

My problem is following: every time I switch between applications the used keyboard layout is changed.
I want to disable such behavior but cannot find such option.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to your control panel and just go to the following options it should work.

. In "Region and Language" - tab-> Keyboards and languages->change keyboard->add->choose your language

2. In "Region and Language" - tab-> administrative->change system locale-> choose your language/country

Comment: Current system locale is set to "German" but this doesn't influence on problem. Current layout is always reset to English (which is Default)